# LWC - Issue pushing value into the array

Tags: lightning-web-components, array, push

I'm having an issue with adding value into the array.
This is lightning-checkbox-group with one additional "None of the above" checkbox to the end.
Forget the option #1, 2 and 3 but trying to make handleInputVal to work(pushing value into the array) but it's not quiet working.
Any idea?

.html

```
<template>
  <lightning-checkbox-group name="CheckboxGroup"
                            label="choose one"
                            data-id="checkbox"
                            options={options}
                            value={value}
                            onchange={handleInputVal} required></lightning-checkbox-group>
  <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="None of the above" value="none" onchange={handleUncheck}></lightning-input>
</template>
```

.js

```
get options() {
  return [
    { label: "1", value: "1" },
    { label: "2", value: "2" },
    { label: "3", value: "3" },
  ];
}

value = [];
userChoice = [];

handleInputVal(e) { // expecting this to return it's value which is "none"
  this.value = []; // empty
  this.userChoice = []; // empty
  this.value = e.detail.value; // expecting this to get the value
  this.userChoice.push(this.value); // pushing in the value to the userChoice array
  this.omniApplyCallResp({ userChoice: this.userChoice }); // gets the value from the array
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing an array into an array.

What you need to do is to individually push each scalar value into the user choice array.

The quick way to do this is to use the `spread` operator (`...`).

Like so:

```
this.userChoice.push(...this.value);
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill try this soon and let you know!

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a problem when trying to push an array inside another here:

```
this.userChoice.push(this.value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But can you elaborate more? I still haven't figure this out yet.